# DynamoDB not picking record, if item is added while processing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-streams, amazon-dynamodb-index

I am reading DynamoDB item as a page Size of 10. There is one use case where, the records can be added in DynamoDB while processing DynamoDB. As, we know that the pointer takes care of last Record Read, but suppose if record is added where pointer already visited, in that case the recently added record is not getting picked. So, I want to know is there any process to check, if record added in between, so as we can reinitialize the pointer.

One method: Count no of record in Db at beginning, and at last if count is different then reinitialize pointer.
Any other approach?

Comment: If you genuinely need to deal with the issue of items being inserted behind the 'next pointer' then you presumably also have an issue with previously-read items having been deleted and previous items having been changed. None of these are trivial problems to solve. Understanding what's happening to a DynamoDB table while you're scanning it can potentially be done via DynamoDB Streams.